# JSTL: Empty List doesn't show input fields

Tags: jsp, arraylist, jstl

I'm trying to create a JSP "Edit" page to edit a person's details.
One of the details would be an ArrayList of addresses.
Although the ArrayList might be empty if the person has no addresses.

My issue is with the input fields of the edit page.
I'm attempting to show the ArrayList as follows...

```
   <c:forEach items="${person.details.addressList}" var="address">                  
  <label>Street:
    <input type="text" id="psnStreet"  name="street" value='${address.street}'>   
  </label>
    <label>City:
    <input type="text" id="psnCity"  name="city"  value="${address.city}" >
  </label>
    <label>State:
    <input type="text" id="psnState"  name="state"  value="${address.state}" >
  </label>
    <label>Postal Code:
    <input type="text" id="psnPCode"  name="postalCode"  value="${address.postalCode}" >
  </label>
    <label>Country:
    <input type="text" id="psnCountry"  name="country"  value="${address.country}" >
  </label>
 </c:forEach>
```

The problem is that when the ArrayList is empty, the input fields do not show on the page!  Which pretty much makes it impossible to add an address.

How is this handled with JSTL?

Comment: Just check in controller if list is empty, then prepare the model by simply adding a new address? Or is that illogical?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not put `id` in iteration, because it will make duplicate `id` on your page.

Second, you should check if the list is empty and show the inputs by using

```
<c:if test="${empty person.details.addressList}">
```

Then in else phrase you continue doing iteration.

Comment: Could you read my comments to the answer above and give your input?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle with `<c:if test>` like the following ....

```
//When your array list is not empty,you will see with datas
     <c:if test='${not empty "${person.details.addressList}"}'>
                   <c:forEach items="${person.details.addressList}" var="address">                  
          <label>Street:
            <input type="text" id="psnStreet"  name="street" value='${address.street}'>   
          </label>
            <label>City:
            <input type="text" id="psnCity"  name="city"  value="${address.city}" >
          </label>
            <label>State:
            <input type="text" id="psnState"  name="state"  value="${address.state}" >
          </label>
            <label>Postal Code:
            <input type="text" id="psnPCode"  name="postalCode"  value="${address.postalCode}" >
          </label>
            <label>Country:
            <input type="text" id="psnCountry"  name="country"  value="${address.country}" >
          </label>
         </c:forEach>
        </c:if>
//When your array list is empty,you will see blank fields
        <c:if test="${empty person.details.addressList}">
         <c:forEach items="${person.details.addressList}" var="address">                  
      <label>Street:
        <input type="text" id="psnStreet"  name="street">   
      </label>
        <label>City:
        <input type="text" id="psnCity"  name="city">
      </label>
        <label>State:
        <input type="text" id="psnState"  name="state">
      </label>
        <label>Postal Code:
        <input type="text" id="psnPCode"  name="postalCode">
      </label>
        <label>Country:
        <input type="text" id="psnCountry"  name="country">
      </label>
     </c:forEach>
        </c:if>
```

Comment: But basically you're telling me that I have to duplicate the input fields!  

If the List is NOT empty, show the inputs with the values.
If the List IS empty then I have to show another group of blank input fields.

Is there not another way to do this??

Comment: What is your requirement.? If  your ArrayList is empty, what you want to do.? If your arrayList is empty, you should not add values in your input fields.

Comment: The requirement is to show the input boxes so that the user can edit the existing values, OR add any blank values.

For instance, if the city, state, postalCode and country exist, show input boxes with the values.  But I also need to show the blank input box so the user can add the street.

The problem is that for the addressList fields that are empty (such as street in this example) the input box doesn't show.

Comment: What if only SOME of the fields have values?  The JSTL will not show an input box for the blank value.